# Unable to use String.split on string with ^ (caret) symbol

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string 218~2~4~6^219~1~3~3^218~5~2~2^217~10~3~8^, I want to split the string by using character with ^ . I have tried  like this

```
String mainString = "218~2~4~6^219~1~3~3^218~5~2~2^217~10~3~8^";

String[] tokens = mainString.split("^");

for (String stri: tokens){
        System.out.println("\nString tokens: " + stri);
    }
```

But It didn't work.. Please help me to split the string

Comment: Escape the character. Try `mainString.split("\\^")`

Comment: Java's `String.split()` method is fraught with problematic edge cases. If you're able to use the excellent [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, make sure to check out its [`Splitter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) class, which is much easier to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `backslash(\)` in front of `^` since its an special character(matches the beginning of the string) in regular expression. Once you add `backslash(\)`  in the front, its treats `^` as a literal, which you require to perform the split.

```
 String[] tokens = mainString.split("\\^");
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you need to escape the `^` symbol because it is a special character that means "the start of the line" in regular expression syntax.